# what's wrong of the ridge regression gradient descent function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, gradient-descent

I code the python function but the prediction doesn't accord with the fact.The price it predicts is negative. However, I cant't find where it is wrong. It is right or not when I compute the derivative[i] and weight[i]? please help.
[image: the function]
[image: the function]
following is a function which the function in picture use:

```
def feature_derivative_ridge(errors, feature, weight, l2_penalty, feature_is_constant):
    # If feature_is_constant is True, derivative is twice the dot product of errors and feature
    if feature_is_constant == True:
       derivative = 2*np.dot(errors, feature)
    # Otherwise, derivative is twice the dot product plus 2*l2_penalty*weight
    else:
        derivative = (2*np.dot(errors, feature) + 2*l2_penalty*weight)
    return derivative
```

Answer (score 0):

oh,I have found the answer.

First: errors = output - predictions 
should be : errors = predictions

then: weights[i] = (1-....
should be: weights[i] = weights[i] - step_size*derivative[i]
(recall the formula)

finally, the output is right